# Add an image to a moving object?

Tags: java, image

I have a class called vbPop (which is basically just a player) and it is just a rectangle right now, i wanted to ask how to load an image instead of just a rectangle?

This is the constructor:

```
public vbPop(Color c, int x, int y, int n) {
    this.colour = c;
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;
    this.vakNummer = n; 
}
```

and the code to draw is:

```
public void draw (Graphics g){
    g.setColor(this.colour);
    g.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(posX, posY, width, height);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `BufferedImage` to your player object, e.g

`try { 
     img =             ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img.png"));
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}`

"/img.png" is a relativ path, in this case img.png is located in your source folder.

afterwards you can display your image in the `draw()` method so:

`g.drawImage( img, posX, posY, width, heigth, null);`

Comment: it says that something has to be catched or something>

Comment: and that the input == null?

Comment: where is the source folder with netbeans?

Comment: the "src" folder of your Java project where your packages/classes are in